# Doctrine 2.0 entity with relations - delete record

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony

When I delete record from Entity with relations (@onetoone or @onetomany)
All relations records will deleted too

```
    $em = $this->getEm();
    $post = $em->find('Blog\\WebBundle\\Entity\\Posts', $pid);
    // not found
    if (!$post) {
        throw ExceptionController::notFound('The post does not exist.');
    }
    $em->remove($post);
    $em->flush();

    return $this->redirectGenerate('_posts');
```

For example this code, remove user, that create post too, because between posts and users there is a relations
How to avoid this?

Comment: Sounds like you have `cascade={"remove"}` or `cascade={"all"}` on the association in Post.

Comment: @rojoca thanks, but it starting working fine, when I change mapping type from yml to annotations :)

Comment: In case it helps anyone else: in my case it turned out to be the database, not Doctrine, that was doing a cascade delete, so check your database to make sure you don't have an `ON DELETE CASCADE` somewhere that you forgot about. If you used Doctrine's `orm:schema-tool` command to generate your SQL, it puts `ON DELETE CASCADE` statements in automatically for those associations marked cascade...make sure to be more careful than I was when copying and pasting.